# How to find the Relationship of two different Data?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

May I know if there is a way to use google sheet tools to find the relationship between two different data? For example: I have 50 respondents in Google Forms, 20 males and 30 females. There is one single-choice question, "Are you happy today?" Now, I want to find out the percentage (or number) of Males and Females who answered "Yes". Is this possible?

I tried counting manually but it took me a long time because there are many different questions. I hope that there is a command that can help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, you should provide way more of context and programming language or environment you would like to develop this. Also, I would not call 'relationship' between different data, it's called simple descriptive statistics. 

That ratio (or proportion) you mentioned would be (males_yes / males_total) *100  , and so on ..  Before your post get banned, add some information of your trials, show us you are trying on something..

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Show your data sample.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something alike:

```
=BYROW(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>"")),LAMBDA(z,{z,TO_PERCENT(COUNTIFS(A:A,z,B:B,"Yes")/COUNTIF(A:A,z))}))
```

[image]